# JavaScript utilities to map properties between objects

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

Are there any 'utility-belt' libraries (thinking underscore.js) that essist in mapping to other classes with different schemas?

Just one example :-

```
var results = {
  "d": {
    "results":
        {
        "ContentTypeID": "0x0100EF81D4A521AFFB4A810FD140B2C3A516",
        "Title": "Acme",
        "ID": 1234
        }       
    }
}
```

Mapped to

```
var customer = {
    "Customer": "Acme",
    "ID": 1234
}
```

- ID = ID
- Title = Customer
- ContentTypeID not represented

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS has a pretty nice concept of data stores which you can do mapping like you described.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore

Ember also has data models / stores.